# Instruments not detecting a memory leak in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, instruments

I have been puzzling over this for days now.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around memory management in objective-c.

Here is my snippet (condensed for clarity):

```
- (void)performOperation:(NSString *)operation
{
    if ([@"+" isEqual:operation]) 
    {
        waitingOperation = operation;
    }
    else if ([@"C" isEqual:operation])
    {
        waitingOperation = nil;
    }

}
```

waitingOperation is merely a local private NSString (no @property, no @synthesize, no getters/setters).

Shouldn't I be leaking memory when I assign waitingOperation to nil when it's currently pointing to an NSString on the heap?  My call to this method is in an ios app that is passing NSString from UILabel display.text.  I've been profiling this code with Instruments and I never see any leaks.  I would really appreciate some clarity on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't laid a claim of ownership on `waitingOperation` by calling `retain`, so you have no responsibility to `release`.

This may lay you open to problems at some point if the string is released elsewhere (by disposing of the `UILabel` for example), in which case you'll be left with a dangling pointer. But you aren't leaking anything here.

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  I think this makes sense now.  I actually misstated UILabel.  It's really UIButton.  I see that an object exists for each button on the heap for the duration of the application's life.  No leaks, and my temporary pointer to those button objects are safe for the duration of the app. I hope I'm understanding this correctly.

Comment: Also, is this form recommended or should I be retaining and then releasing this UIButton object within an ios app?

Comment: @Tom If the button is in a NIB file you don't need to manage it separately from that. But if you're storing and using references to objects like buttons in a way that could stray outside the scope of their container then you need to manage that external ownership explicitly.